# Checking for upper/lower case and symbols and digits in a variable python

Tags: python

Im currently using regex to check for them seperately so I would prefer an answer using re.

An example of what I am using to find them seperately:

```
 if re.search(r'[A-Z]', userpass):
    score += 5
```

However, I want to check if the variable has all of the paramaters(upper/lower case and symbols and digits) so using the re.search would return true every time since it would just check for example if there is one digit but I want to check if there is a digit, a uppercase and lowercase, and a symbol. And also the symbols I want to check for are: !$%^&*()-_=+

also to clarfy, I am quite new to python so nearly everything is new to me apart from basic stuff so Im using regex as I find it quite simple

Comment: So you want to verify that the userpass has at least one of each type, regardless of order.  Is this correct?

Comment: @hoefling would i still use re.search? I dont want to see if there is one digit, i want to see if there is one digit, upper/lower case and symbol

Comment: @greg muelller yes

Comment: @hoefling's suggestion doesn't reference symbols, just alphanumeric characters, so you might need a little more than that

Comment: ah, so you want to check that a string has at least one digit and at least one lowercase and at least one uppercase? So e.g. `1Az` is valid, but `Az` is not? If yes, then forget the regex I mentioned earlier.

Comment: yes but i also need to check for those symbols.( !$%^&*()-_=+)

Answer (score 0):

I think it may just be more suited to *not* use a regex for this. Rather, I would just use `all()` and `any()`:

```
checks = [[chr(c) for c in range(97, 123)] + [chr(c) for c in range(65, 91)], list("!$%^&*()-_=+"), [str(i) for i in range(10)]]

if all(any(c in check for c in userpass) for check in checks):
    score += 5
```

Answer (score 0):

For a non-regex solution you can use something like:

```
def check_userpass(userpass):
    has_lower = userpass.upper() != userpass
    has_upper = userpass.lower() != userpass
    has_number = any(ch.isdigit() for ch in userpass)
    has_symbol = any(ch in "!$%^&*()-_=+" for ch in userpass)
    return has_lower and has_upper and has_number and has_symbol
```

Comment: so then if i would want to add 10 to their score if this was true what would i put?

Answer (score 0):

without regex:

```
cond1 = any(c.isalpha() for c in password)
cond2 = any(c.isnumber() for c in password)
cond3 = any(word in password for word in '!$%^&*()-_=+')
valid = cond1 and cond2 and cond3
```

Answer (score 0):

One way is to just use `any` instead of regular expressions

```
if any(c.isupper() for c in userpass) and any(c.islower() for c in userpass) and any(c.isdigit() for c in userpass) and any(c in '!$%^&*()-_=+' for c in userpass):
    ...
```

But that can get rather wordy.  If our checks are functions we can pass character to, we can do

```
def ispunc(c):
    return c in '!$%^&*()-_=+'

criteria = (str.isupper, str.islower, str.isdigit, ispunc)

if all(any(check(c) for c in userpass) for check in criteria):
   ...
```