# Validating an alphabetical AND numerical input in Python

Tags: python, validation

I’m trying to do some coding for a project where I will need to validate an input containing both alphabetical and numerical characters, like this

“harry23”

I want to validate to ensure the input has BOTH alphabetical and numerical characters, ideally without creating a huge block of code. My school isn’t keen on downloading complex libraries either, so if there’s a way to code it myself without relying on loads of mods i’d appreciate it. 
Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to SO. It'd be great if you could show what you've tried so far, as this is really how this platform works, you'll get help once you've shown some effort ;), try starting for example [here](http://www.pythoncentral.io/how-to-check-if-a-string-is-a-number-in-python-including-unicode/)

Comment: Regular expressions (re) module is part of the standard library, that's what you need. https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html

Comment: Also, as a general rule keep in mind that SO is not a free coding service.

Comment: [The answers to this question from yesterday may help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47422360/checking-for-upper-lower-case-and-symbols-and-digits-in-a-variable-python/47422571#47422571) (I can't find a good duplicate for this, but my instinct says there has to be one). I don't think regex is a good solution for this.

Answer (score 2):

I think you create two function like this ones :

This one will return true if your string as one digit at least

```
>>> def hasNumbers(inputString):
...     return any(char.isdigit() for char in inputString)
```

and this one will return true if you string as one char at least

```
>>> def hasChar(inputString):
...     return any(char.isalpha() for char in inputString)
```

and you can check if it has both by doing

```
if(hasNumbers("Charlie123") and hasChar("Charlie123"))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could always try substring checks for validation. You can alter them to incude upper/lower case and numbers, if need be.

Here's a quick example:

```
if "substring" not in somestring: 
     print("Error!")
```

You could put this in a `while True` loop and have a ValueError clause.

```
while True:
     try:
          //input
     if "substring" not in somestring:
          continue
     except ValueError:
          continue:
     else:
          break
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use an intersection based set approach for some quite concise,
extensible code:

```
import string

letters = set(string.ascii_letters)
nums = set(string.digits)

def has_alnum(word):
    chars = set(word)
    return chars & letters and chars & nums
```

If you're particularly interested in speed, it will likely be faster to just
write out the loop by hand:

```
def loop_has_alnum(word):
    letter = False
    num = False
    for ch in word:
        if ch in letters:
            if num:
                return True
            letter = True
        elif ch in nums:
            if letter:
                return True
            num = True
    return False
```

Having put these in an `ipy` file, I did a little testing:

```
words = ["harry23", "a1", "8aaaa", "bbb0", "abc", "jim", "123"]

for word in words:
    print("{:7} - {!s:5} - {}".format(word, bool(has_alnum(word)), loop_has_alnum(word)))

print("timing sets:")

%timeit [has_alnum(word) for word in words]

print("timing loop:")

%timeit [loop_has_alnum(word) for word in words]
```

with the following results:

```
harry23 - True  - True
a1      - True  - True
8aaaa   - True  - True
bbb0    - True  - True
abc     - False - False
jim     - False - False
123     - False - False
timing sets:
3.32 µs ± 13.8 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
timing loop:
2.47 µs ± 130 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

Demonstrating that they both agree, but the loop is a little faster.